# Do we live in a simulation?

Tags: simulated-worlds

If we live in a virtual reality, then why do we never see people or objects appear or disappear suddenly? Is this proof that we do not exist in a simulation?

Comment: Unless this is a badly worded question about how you'd write a fictional world in which reality was a simulation, it doesn't belong on the Worldbuilding SE. Try [Philosophy.SE](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: How would I transfer this question over to Philosophy.SE ?

Comment: That, I do not know. I'd simply go re-ask it there myself, but I think there's also ways for mods to move them between SE's. I've flagged it already, so they might be able to migrate it for you.

Comment: Because the (hypothetical) virtual reality doesn't run under Windoze :-)

Comment: If you ask it on Philosophy, take the time to write more than 2 sentences.  It makes things a lot easier on them (Philosophy does best if they can get a glimmer into your background to select the best answer.  Questions like this have a billion answers, both positive and negative)

Comment: Presumably the rules of the simulation do not allow objects to suddenly disappear.  Reality must be "consistent".

Comment: Like Cort Ammon mentioned, this question just doesn't seem to be a good fit for the network at large at present. And **please don't just repost a question on a different site.** Moderators have the ability to migrate a question to any site. With this specific question, **if it gets edited here** to match the Philosophy SE standards, it can be subsequently flagged and migrated. As it stands, if this question were to be migrated to Philosophy, it would probably just end up being closed there, causing the migration to be rejected and annoying everyone involved. // cc @plagueheart

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Ah, thank you. I'm new to SE so I didn't know how the migration worked.

Answer (score 1):

No.  We could be either real, or living in a well-programmed simulation, or unable to notice glitches (since this is the world we live in; eg: do you think a Sim notices pixelation?).

Doesn't prove anything.

How do you know that things *don't* disappear?  You've never misplaced anything?  Just because the control program has noticed you searching for something; thus runs a check on items, finds that one has been lost, then (sometimes!) places the item in an out-of-the-way spot that you haven't checked - or have already checked once or twice!  I think this would be the *definition* of a disappearing item in the context of a program of simulated reality.

Answer (score 0):

Existence does not have to be "real". Reality is a moot point. There is no sufficient assertion what reality is or should be. We authenticate ourselves. We do not need an authority figure to do that for us. If one wants to exist, yes, go ahead. If one wants to debase self and not exist, the same applies.

The question mentions "people or objects appear or disappear suddenly". That is quantum mechanics, which simply means we do not have any empirical evidence yet to make any logical assertions on that level. We will have that in a few years, then we will have a new quantum level which will represent what we have not come to understand yet.